# Import a python module from within a packed module

Tags: python-3.x, python-module, python-packaging

So I [builded a python package](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) localy:

```
cgi@cgires:~$ pip list | grep mads
madscgi                     0.1.0
```

Its nice! Afterwards I can use it in Jupyter Notebook, in iPython Shell, in Python Shell and even in python scripts *outside the modules code*. So it works as expected 100% outside the modules code:

[image: working_outside_the_packaged code]

Thats nice, but next I want to import code from one builded module (*inside* the package) into another python file (*inside* the package). Lets name it `import_test.py` and try it out:

[image: working_packaging]

So it fails if it is getting executed in the directory, where the package is build from. And it looks like, that the `python interpreter` is taking the parent directory (with the **same name** like the module) and this is failing.

Is is possible to enforce the usage of the installed pip-package?

Comment: The description really does not make it clear which modules are trying to import what, and where these are in relation to one another. Please [edit] your post to provide a minimal, reproducible example as copyable text, not images. Is there a file ``/home/cgi/mads_remote/mads_pkg/mads_cons/mads_cons.py``? What is the value of ``mads_cons.__file__`` if ``import_test.py`` just does ``import mads_cons``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You pointed it out! I had a python file `/home/cgi/mads_remote/mads_pkg/mads_cons/mads_cons.py`. I renamed it to `mads_connections.py` and it works - So I will never use the same name in parent-directory and the files in the future.

Comment: Could you create a short anwer or should I? So we can close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MisterMiyagi pointed out, the problem was, that there were an upper folder which had the same name as the module.

Here: `mads_cons` is the upper folder from `import_test.py`. Therefore, the upper folder is getting imported instead of the via pip installed module. Thats it.

Answer (score -2):

The file you want to import should either be in the same folder or referred to with the absolute path of it.

If that doesn't suit you, you can call sys.path

```
import sys

sys.path
```

You can keep your file in any of the directories sys.path returns.

Smart would be, if you keep the file inside.

> ......../site-packages/

Comment: Code has been in the right place. It was just an issue of the direction in which python imports the modules/files